# Is it possible to construct a string in Javascript which has 'variables' built in?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a PDF with some scripting, and I am applying code to fields using the console and some simple loops to save on repeated efforts. In some cases, I am applying a custom calculation script to a field where one integer needs to change from one field to the next. If all the scripts were the same, I would run this in the debugger console:

```js
var s = "if(this.getField(\"Span A\").value >= 60){\n\
    event.value = Math.round(((this.getField(\"Span A\").value*41500 - 1674500)/233));\n\
}else{\n\
    event.value = Math.round((this.getField(\"Span A\").value*3500/60));\n\
}";

for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++){
    var f = this.getField(getNthFieldName(i));
    if(f.name.match(/quant a/i) != null){
        var n = f.name.match(/\d/g);
        f.setAction("Calculate", s);
    }
}
```

I have many 'Quant' fields, and each group (A, B, etc) will have a similar calculation. The fields are name "Quant A1", "Quant A2" etc. Quant A1 needs to calculate with the input from Span A1.

In the above script, it would be really cool if I could have a variable within the script string that I can pass a value (n) to be plugged in to the string, essentially the same way a function call works.

Is this possible?

Here is my fantasy version of what I imagine it could look like (this is just to further explain my intent; I don't think this would actually work this way):

```js
var s(x) = "if(this.getField(\"Span A\""x").value >= 60){\n\
    event.value = Math.round(((this.getField(\"Span A\""x").value*41500 - 1674500)/233));\n\
}else{\n\
    event.value = Math.round((this.getField(\"Span A\""x").value*3500/60));\n\
}";

for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++){
    var f = this.getField(getNthFieldName(i));
    if(f.name.match(/quant a/i) != null){
        var n = f.name.match(/\d/g);
        f.setAction("Calculate", s(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to re-invent [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: As mentioned above, template strings are the way to do this. However, why do you need a string of code like this? If you are planning on using `eval()`, I would strongly suggest against it.

Comment: you can only do it *with* a function call, though template literals would make doing so far easier

Comment: Not re-invent, but maybe discover? I was unaware of template literals. Can anyone help me understand how I would make use of that in this context? I am by no means a professional programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use string litterals if you're useing ES6 and higher.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals?retiredLocale=nl

```js
const greetings = "I'm a variable!";
let string = `Hi! this is a variable: ${greetings}`;

console.log(string);
```

Otherwise concatenate it with the + operator.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly your question. I think you want to use template literals.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Use backticks instead of " or ' to insert your variables inside a string.

```
const a ='Cheese'
const b= 'is Delicious'
```

`${a} ${b}` will output 'Cheese is Delicious'